# Cannot set Cache-Control headers with gzippo

Tags: node.js, express, http-headers, gzippo

I have trouble setting the max-age header while using a gzippo server.

### Test with express:

**express.js:**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.configure(function () {
  app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('foo', 'bar');
    return next();
  });
});

var connect = require('connect');
connect.createServer(
  connect.static("" + __dirname + "/dist")
).listen(8090);
```

Then I do:

```
node express.js
# go to localhost:8090/test.html (just come static html file)
```

headers are:

```
Cache-Control:public, max-age=0 
no foo header
```

### Test with gzippo:

**gzippo.js**

```
var gzippo = require('gzippo');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.configure(function () {
  app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('foo', 'bar');
    return next();
  });
});

app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(gzippo.staticGzip("" + __dirname + "/dist", {maxAge: 0, clientMaxAge: 0}), {maxAge: 0, clientMaxAge: 0});

app.listen(8090);
```

Then I do:

```
node gzippo.js
# go to localhost:8090/test.html
```

Headers are:

```
foo:bar
Cache-Control:public, max-age=604800
```

If I try setting `res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'max-age=0')` just after setting foo, max age stays 604800 in my response header.

---

My questions are:

- Why isn't foo header set in my express.js server?
- And more importantly, **why is max-age header not set to 0, despite trying to set it manually, and as an option to gzippo** ?

Gzippo doc: https://github.com/tomgco/gzippo

Answer (score 1):

> Why isn't foo header set in my express.js server?

Express exposes a different API than `res.setHeader()` for setting headers in responses.

You should be using `res.set('HEADER', 'VALUE')` according to the [express documentation](http://expressjs.com/3x/api.html#res.set)

> And more importantly, why is max-age header not set to 0, despite
>   trying to set it manually, and as an option to gzippo ?

So I've looked into gizippo's code, it does the following at initialization time:

`var maxAge = options.maxAge || 86400000,`

So if you pass 0 as `maxAge`, javascript's evaluation will be

`var maxAge = 0 || 86400000,`

**As a consequence**, maxAge will be 86400000!

Hope this helps, Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like they have a wrapper called `set()`

```
res.set('Content-Type', 'text/plain');

res.set({
  'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
  'Content-Length': '123',
  'ETag': '12345'
})
```

http://expressjs.com/api.html

Aliased as res.header(field, [value]).

Comment: Thanks. But If I try, for example: `res.set({'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0'});` in `app.use`, it doesn't change the header. If I try setting 'Content-Type' like this, the server never responds. Am I missing something?

Comment: Try it without the object syntax, like `res.set(foo, bar)` instead of `res.set({foo: bar})`

Comment: I tried it. In chrome response headers, I still have `Cache-Control:public, max-age=604800` (event after disabling cache in chrome dev tools, or incognito mode). But with `curl -I`, I see `Cache-Control: max-age=0`

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using express with the .compress() option

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var modRewrite = require('connect-modrewrite');
//var fs = require('fs');

app.configure(function () {
  app.use(modRewrite([
    '!(\\..+)$ / [L]'
  ]));
});

app.use(express.compress());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
var oneMinuteInMs = 60000;
// maxAge is 0 if you don't specify it
app.use(express.static("" + __dirname + "/dist", { maxAge: oneMinuteInMs })); 

app.listen(8080);
```